# Connecting QGIS to remote Ubuntu PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am trying to connect to a remote postgis 2.0 server (Ubuntu) from QGIS 2.0.1 (installed on winxp). I have been working with QGIS 1.7 / 1.8 on the same database for almost a year without any issue.

But I recently installed QGIS 2.0 and although everything seems to work fine, when I load a layer it has no rows at all, and when I try to exit QGIS it crashes. It raises a warning saying that:

> cursor 1 is lost

Could anybody give me some advice?


The log displays something like 20 PostGIS error messages, like this:

```
SQL: DECLARE qgisf0_11 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary(ST_Force2D("the_geom"),'NDR'),"id_column"FROM"schema"."table"WHERE"the_geom"&&st_makeenvelope(41.5457,35.544,36.784254,44.15748)
Resultado:7(ERROR: function st_force2d(geometry) does not exist
LINE1: ...RE qgis0_11 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary(ST_Force2D...
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The actual name of the function in PostGIS 2.0, and also in postgis 1.5 is st_force_2d(geometry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been solved in [this commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/5bdb7952f651f4628f5d702770367b25077e1554).

Please try a development snapshot (nightly/master/qgis-dev from OSGeo4W) where this should be solved. It is possible, that a bugfix release (2.0.2) will solve this issue and (almost) certain that the next release 2.2 will contain this fix.